# How can I got a point's GPS position when select it on the static map

Tags: google-maps-api-2

Firstly,I use google static map API to get the image to display on html/wml.
And then, I want to get the point's GPS position where user pressed on the image.

Is there some way to get the GPS position if I got the co-ordinates on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is probably not. You can't be sure exactly what the static map's dimensions are (the server might change the location slightly to fit things better, etc.). If you're just asking for a map by `center` and `zoom` then you stand a slightly better chance, but it will still be tricky.

If you're trying to add *dynamic* behaviour to a *static* map, have you considered instead the [Maps JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)? Finding the coordinates of where a user clicks is trivial there. (Also, you can disable the zooming, panning, controls, etc. if you want so that it still feels like it's static).

Comment: I've tried Maps Javascript API, but it seems implemented by flash? But my running environment can't support flash. It only supports html+javascript

Comment: No, the Maps JavaScript API is not flash – it's pure HTML+JS. (There is a flash API, but it is completely separate.)

Comment: Umm... My running environment(TV set-top box) only supports js1.5. 

Maybe it's not enough to running  Maps JavaScript API?